# How to bind dynamic complex objects created using partial-view to a collection property in view-model

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, c#-4.0, asp.net-core-mvc, partial-views

I'm unable to bind a collection of child-complext objects created dynamically using a partial-view to view-model `IEnumerable`  property.

I have successfully bound objects created dynamically using partial-views to a view-model using a technique I found on this blog https://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/. I have followed the same technique but I'm unable to bind a collection to a `IEnumerable` property in a view-model.

```
[BindRequired]
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
   other properties....
   public IEnumerable<ContactDetailViewModel> EmployeeContact { get; set; }
}

[BindRequired]
public class ContactDetailViewModel
{
   // I use this as my indexer for dynamic elements
   public string RecordId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

   public string Telephone { get; set; }

   public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

   public string ContactDescription { get; set; }
}
```

I call into this action-method via ajax to add dynamic contact detail elements and it returns the partial-view as html and it works fine.

```
[Route("[action]", Name = "BlankEmployeeContactDetail"), HttpGet("AddBlankContactDetail")]
public PartialViewResult AddBlankContactDetail()
{
            return PartialView("_ContactInformation", new     ContactDetailViewModel());
}
```

The initial contact detail is added to the main-view using the following, kindly follow this link https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkRSHVUtFlKhuHaxH96Ik4ineATE to download the main view and partial-view cshtml files. It is also noteworthy to mention that model binding fails for all other properties when I include this partial-view but works when I comment it out. I'm baffled and would greatly appreciate any help you can afford me.

```
<section id="widget-grid" class="">
   <div class="row contactContainer">
     @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ContactInformation", new ContactDetailViewModel()); }
   </div>
</section>
```

This is the controller action method I'm trying to bind posted data to:

```
[Route("[action]"), HttpPost, AllowAnonymous, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Register([FromForm] EmployeeViewModel model, [FromQuery] string returnUrl = null)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand where you are model binding anything here. Your action has no parameters and you instantiate your view model directly.

Comment: Good day, thank you for the comment, I attached the controller in the link above, but I will edit to include the action method that receives the posted data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to bind, the input names much follow a particular convention that maps to what you're binding to. While it's unclear from your question, my best guess is that you're trying to ultimately bind to an instance of `EmployeeViewModel`, which means that your contact information inputs would need names like: `EmployeeContact[0].Telephone`, but when you pass an instance of `ContactDetailViewModel` along as the "model" of the partial view, the names will be just `Telephone`, and worse, these same names will be repeated over and over, i.e. each contact information set of fields you create will all have an input named just `Telephone`.

Long and short, you need the context of the whole model to generate the correct input names. You have a couple of options.

Since you're retrieving the set of fields via an AJAX request, it would be possible to pass the "prefix" to use along with that request. In other words, you can keep track of an index value, counting how many of these sections you've added, and then send along with the request for a new section something like

```
prefix: 'EmployeeContact[' + (i + 1) + ']',
```

Then, in your partial view:

```
@{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ContactInformation", new ContactDetailViewModel(), new ViewDataDictionary { TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = ViewBag.Prefix } } ); }
```

That's a little hacky, and honestly probably rather prone to error, though. The better option would be to take an entirely different approach. Instead of calling back to get the partial view, define it just once as a template:

```
<script type="text/html" id="ContactInformationTemplate">
    <!-- HTML for contact information inputs -->
</script>
```

Then, using a library like Vue, React, Angular, etc., you can set up a "foreach" construction tied to a particular JavaScript array which uses this template to render items in that array. Then, adding a new set of inputs is as simple as adding a new item to the array. You will have to do some works to customize the input names based on the index of the item in the array, but all of these client-side frameworks have ways to do that. That would also have the side benefit of not having to make an AJAX request every time you want to add a new section.

Comment: Good day, thank you for your kind comment, I have done so and it is working fine now. It wasn't working because of this ```name="EmployeeContact[@(Model.RecordId)].ContactDescription"```, I was using ```name="model[@(Model.RecordId)].ContactDescription"``` so using the property name helps the model binder to understand how to associate what elements with what properties. I struggled for the whole day with this and I even developed a gnawing headache that I'm nursing now.

Comment: I'm using ```public string RecordId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();``` to generate an indexer and it works like charm and that explains this line of code ```new ContactDetailViewModel()```